# Sql Server Select Statement, Cumulative column

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, join

I have the select statement below which is used in a gridview datasource. I need the cumulative column to be calculated on the ProjInstDate like I have below. But if you see the results, I get duplicates on the cumulative totals for the same date, which makes sense. But what I can't figure out is how to have the cumulative be calculated on the ProjInstDate but do it for the different JobIDs.  I'm not sure what the select statement is supposed to be like at this point "(t1.ProjectedInstDate >=     t2.ProjectedInstDate) ". I know that right here is the issue but I'm not sure how to properly do what I want.

```
select t1.JobID
     , t1.JobName
     , t1.[JobDescription]
     , t1.JobType
     , Convert(varchar, t1.QuoteDate, 101) AS QuoteDate
     , t1.ProjectedInstDate
     , Convert(decimal(12, 0), t1.QuoteTotal) AS QuoteTotal
     , Convert(decimal(12, 0), t1.Prob) AS Prob
     , t1.Completed
     , t1.ProjectManager
     , Convert(decimal(12, 0), t1.ProjectedIncome) AS ProjectedIncome
     , sum(CASE WHEN t1.Completed != 'y' and t1.Prob != 0 
                then Convert(decimal(12, 0),t2.ProjectedIncome) 
                else null end) As CumulativeProjectedIncome
     , Convert(decimal(12, 1), sum(CASE WHEN t1.Completed != 'y' and t1.Prob != 0 
                                        then (t2.ProjectedIncome/1923) 
                                        else null end)) as DAYSOFWORK
     , (CASE WHEN t1.Completed != 'y'and t1.Prob != 0 
             then Convert(decimal(12, 0), (datediff(day, GetDate(), t1.ProjectedInstDate))) 
             else null end) AS DAYSFROMTODAY 
     , (CASE WHEN t1.Completed != 'y' and t1.Prob != 0 
             then Convert(decimal(12, 1), sum(t2.ProjectedIncome/1923)-datediff(day, GetDate(), t1.ProjectedInstDate)) 
             else null end) as DAYSOFREVASOFTODAY
  from ContractPlan t1 
 inner join 
       ContractPlan t2 
    on (t1.ProjectedInstDate >= t2.ProjectedInstDate) 
 where (t2.Completed = 'n' or t2.Completed = 'N') 
   and (t1.Completed = 'N' or t1.Completed = 'n')
 Group By  
       t1.JobID
     , t1.JobName
     , t1.[JobDescription]
     , t1.JobType
     , t1.QuoteDate
     , t1.ProjectedInstDate
     , t1.QuoteTotal
     , t1.Prob
     , t1.ProjectedIncome
     , t1.Completed
     , t1.ProjectManager 
 Order By 
       t1.ProjectedInstDate




ProjInstDate      | QuoteTotal | Prob |Comp | PM| ProjectedIncome | CumulativeIncome
2014-04-16 00:00:00 300 100 N   NULL    300 300
2014-04-17 00:00:00 6000    100 N   NULL    6000    6300
2014-04-18 00:00:00 300 100 N   NULL    300 6600
2014-05-01 00:00:00 9756    100 N   NULL    9756    63637
2014-05-01 00:00:00 28796   75  N   NULL    21597   63637
2014-05-01 00:00:00 11179   50  N   NULL    5590    63637
2014-05-01 00:00:00 20094   100 N   NULL    20094   63637
2014-05-04 00:00:00 2222    90  N   ben 2000    67637
2014-05-04 00:00:00 2222    90  N   ben 2000    67637
2014-05-05 00:00:00 23698   100 N   daved   23698   98835
2014-05-05 00:00:00 6000    100 N   sdf 6000    98835
2014-05-05 00:00:00 1500    100 N   NULL    1500    98835
2014-05-07 00:00:00 4500    100 N   NULL    4500    103335
2014-05-09 00:00:00 750 100 N   NULL    750 104085
2014-05-13 00:00:00 540 100 N   NULL    540 104625
```

Comment: why are you using >= in your logic. to be able to actually join a table you need to join on an id otherwise your join isn't actually doing anything effective. for example: `from ContractPlan t1 inner join ContractPlan t2 on t1.JobID = t2.JobID and t1.ProjectedInstDate >= t2.ProjectedInstDate` may make more sense though i'm not sure  you want to put the comparison in the join itself as opposed to the where clause. if you explain what you are trying to do and what the tables look like a little more clearly that would help

Comment: I have a table which are all the columns in the "group by" part of the select statement. I have a couple calculated columns for forecasting income and how many days until a job, which are all done in the select statement. I am using the inner join so that I can calculate the cumulative project income for all of the jobs, and I originally had it    "t1.JobID >= t2.JobID"   which worked fine, except cumulative was based on the id and not the projected install date, which i need for forecasting. I need the cumulative to be ordered by projected install date but that can only be done in the "on".